# Loading rtf string into TextRange doesnt include line breaks

Tags: c#, rtf, memorystream

I have a method that sets a text range from and rtf string.  My problem is when Loading it into the TextRange, it loses line breaks.  How do I go about making sure my line breaks are there when i load the rtf string from a memory stream?  My method is as follows currently:

```
    public static void LoadRtf(string rtf, TextRange range)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(rtf))
            return;

        using (MemoryStream rtfMemoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (StreamWriter rtfStreamWriter = new StreamWriter(rtfMemoryStream))
            {
                rtfStreamWriter.Write(rtf);
                rtfStreamWriter.Flush();
                rtfMemoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

                range.Load(rtfMemoryStream, DataFormats.Rtf);
            }
        }
    }
```

the calling class that extends RichTextBox

```
public class RtfBox : RichTextBox
{
    public object RtfContent
    {
        get { return GetValue(RtfContentProperty); }
        set { SetValue(RtfContentProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty RtfContentProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("RtfContent", typeof(object), typeof(RtfBox),
                                            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender, RtfContentChanged));

    static void RtfContentChanged(DependencyObject depObj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs evt)
    {
        RtfBox box = depObj as RtfBox;
        if (box == null)
            return;

        string sContent = evt.NewValue as string;
        if (sContent == null)
        {
            byte[] bContent = evt.NewValue as byte[];
            if (bContent != null)
                sContent = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bContent);
        }

        box.Document.Blocks.Clear();

        try
        {
            TextRange range = new TextRange(box.Document.ContentStart, box.Document.ContentEnd);
            FlowDocumentRtfConverter.LoadRtf(sContent, range);

            if (box.Document.FontStyle == FontStyles.Normal)
                box.Document.FontStyle = box.FontStyle;
            if (box.Document.FontWeight == FontWeights.Normal)
                box.Document.FontWeight = box.FontWeight;
            if (box.Document.FontStretch == FontStretches.Normal)
                box.Document.FontStretch = box.FontStretch;

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
        }
    }

    public RtfBox()
        : base()
    {
        IsDocumentEnabled = false;
    }
}
```

my rtf string value im working with currently is this "H\0e\0l\0l\0o\0\r\0\n\02\0n\0d\0 \0l\0i\0n\0e\0\r\0"
Maybe there is something wrong with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the range.Load to use DataFormats.Text and it now takes into account the line breaks.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code with a slight modification as below and it worked for me. Maybe it is the way you are intitializing your text range?

```
        public static string LoadRtf(string rtf, TextRange range)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(rtf))
                return "";

            using (MemoryStream rtfMemoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (StreamWriter rtfStreamWriter = new StreamWriter(rtfMemoryStream))
                {
                    rtfStreamWriter.Write(rtf);
                    rtfStreamWriter.Flush();
                    rtfMemoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

                    range.Load(rtfMemoryStream, DataFormats.Rtf);
                }
            }

            return range.Text;
        }
```

Then I called this code and the string returned has line breaks and shows properly in the rich text box control.

```
string rtf = File.ReadAllText(@"c:\temp\document.rtf");

FlowDocument flowDocument = new FlowDocument();
TextRange range = new TextRange(flowDocument.ContentStart, flowDocument.ContentEnd);

this.richTextBox1.Text = LoadRtf(rtf, range);
```

Comment: I added the calling class if that gives you some more useful information.  Still no luck on my end.

Comment: I change the range.Load to use DataFormats.Text and it now takes into account the line breaks